# png/jpeg dlls needed for SDL2_Image

Tags: c++, dll, sdl

I am trying to use SDL2_Image to load png and jpeg files. However, I have some problems getting proper dll files. Apparently the library needs those two files at runtime:

`libjpeg-8.dll`

`libpng15-15.dll`

Where is a reliable source of those two files or how can I build them myself?
I am using Windows 7 and trying to make a 32-bit application.

There are many copies of those `.dll` files on the web, but every file I check seems to be of different size, so I consider them unreliable - at least until someone tells me *this* is the file...

**libpng**

To get this one working I checked http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html and ended up over here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/. From there I downloaded the latest available version - [lpng1514.7z](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/latest/download?source=files) (+ needed [zlib125.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/zlib/1.2.5/zlib125.zip/download)) and managed to build it, producing `libpng15.dll` - which is *almost* what I need.

As a dirty hack I tried just renaming the file, and it seems to be working so far, but I would prefer to have a proper dll instead.

**libjpeg**

For jpeg I followed http://www.ijg.org/ and ended up downloading [jpegsr8.zip](http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsr8.zip) but I get sources that I am not sure how to build under Windows (using Visual Studio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libpng15.dll` should be good enough, it means it's version 1.5 (the 15_15 must be release 15 of 1.5).

As for `libjpeg`, you could rebuild it yourself. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652178/compiling-libjpeg) for a way to build it on Windows (it's done outside of Visual Studio) using free tools.

You could probably try to adapt the `makefile` to your version of visual studio, but it's probably easier to use MinGW.

I will convert one of my project to `SDL2` this week, I will share my progress if you are still stuck with `SDL2_Image`.

**EDIT** As I told you, I am in the process of porting my own engine to SDL2. When building SDL_image, I noticed an `external` folder in the `VisualC` folder. The `external` folder contains all the `DLL` files used by SDL_Image:

```
31/01/2013  12:54 AM           200,192 libjpeg-8.dll
31/01/2013  12:54 AM           211,456 libpng15-15.dll
31/01/2013  12:54 AM           466,944 libtiff-5.dll
31/01/2013  12:54 AM           222,208 libwebp-2.dll
31/01/2013  12:54 AM             2,998 LICENSE.jpeg.txt
31/01/2013  12:54 AM             4,438 LICENSE.png.txt
31/01/2013  12:54 AM             1,294 LICENSE.tiff.txt
31/01/2013  12:54 AM             1,653 LICENSE.webp.txt
31/01/2013  12:54 AM             1,450 LICENSE.zlib.txt
31/01/2013  12:54 AM            90,624 zlib1.dll
              10 File(s)      1,203,257 bytes
```

So no need to build anything, just sync from the Mercurial repository located here: http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL_image/

Comment: Thanks for the link! Please do let me know about your progress. I would like to know even if I get unstuck myself (and I am almost there thanks to your responses)

Answer (score 2):

`gnuplot` has prebuilt binaries for Windows, which has those DLLs, see http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/gnuplot/gnuplot/4.6.0/gp460win32.zip for example.

or

`Gimp for Windows` installs whole bunch of DLLs including `libjpeg-8.dll` and `libpng15-15.dll` see, [http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/gimp-win/GIMP%20%2B%20GTK%2B%20%28stable%20release%29/GIMP%202.8.2/gimp-2.8.2-setup-1.exe](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/gimp-win/GIMP%20+%20GTK+%20%28stable%20release%29/GIMP%202.8.2/gimp-2.8.2-setup-1.exe)

Comment: Thank you. It definitely helps on `jpeg` end, but it is using `png14-14` instead of `15-15`.

Comment: While it is good to obtain prebuilt binaries from somewhere, for a serious project I wouldn't rely on third parties to provide me with libraries and would make sure my build process allows me to build them when needed