# Kakadu JPEG compression library

Tags: java, c++, c, jpeg

This question might not be suitable for this site, but after long search, I have come here to ask experts.

I am going to work with `JPEG` compression. The library I have to use is `Kakadu 2.2`. However I haven't found any `documentation` stating all the functions/methods the library provides like other api do (Android, Windows Phone etc).

So the question is, is there any `documentation or list of all functions` that I can use for development.

Regards

Comment: According to the Kadaku website, "Kakadu comes with an extensively hyperlinked, automatically extendable documentation system, which currently includes almost 1000 HTML pages."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Kakadu is closed source, they don't provide good documentation for free on the internet. If you've purchased their product, you should ask them for a list of functions, or simply peruse the source code where possible.

If you have any choice in the matter then you may be better off with libjpeg as it's free and pretty standard. Then again, I have no idea what you are using this for.

Comment: It is available in executable format. I am not sure if I can use it with Visual Studio or eclipse. are openjpeg & kakadu similar? What is kdu?

Comment: Right. It's in closed source format - that means they want to charge you for the documentation you are seeking. libjpeg implements everything you should ever need to do with jpegs, and yes it can work with any IDE. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652178/compiling-libjpeg has a nice list of ways to compile it for various set-ups. As for Kdu, I don't know much about it.