# Type 'FILE' has not been declared jpeglib.h

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse

Im using eclipse neon2, Windows 10 and i have compiled jpeglib as following the instructions ( using MinGW) (first answer):

[Compiling libjpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652178/compiling-libjpeg)

But in my program after compiling and building im facing this error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type 'FILE' has not been
>   declared  MyBilliards     line 974, external location:
>   c:\mingw\include\jpeglib.h    C/C++ Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type 'FILE' has not been
>   declared  MyBilliards     line 975, external location:
>   c:\mingw\include\jpeglib.h    C/C++ Problem

But if i skip and launch the project with these errors, it seems to work fine...

Also if someone has a tutorial how to make mingw and jpeglib work in eclipse and windows10 would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if someone has the same problem i solved it including stdio.h BEFORE jpeglib.h ( which is strange as in the main.cpp i didnt get any dependency or syntax error). Then clean project and then Build All....

So

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<jpeglib.h>
```