# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol (libJPEG compiling and linking)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, libjpeg, linker-errors

I have been trying real hard to get libJPEG 9b to work on my Visual Studio Community 2017 project. I have tried a few methods:

- Using **NMake** from Visual studio Command Prompt which gave me jpeg.sln and apps.sln, I built those and got cjpeg.exe and djpeg.exe which seem to be working. I have no idea how to link that library even now to my current project and make it work like a normal library!
- I followed the **MinGW** instructions on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652178/compiling-libjpeg), which gave me .a, .la and .dll.a files. After this I added the include and lib directory paths in my project properties and the .a library file in the linker properties. I also copy-pasted the .h files in my project directory.

I am trying out the code given [here](https://gist.github.com/PhirePhly/3080633).
Now, I seem to be getting a bunch of linking errors.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: JpegReadWrite, Configuration: Debug x64 --- 
1>JpegReadWrite.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol     jpeg_std_error referenced in function main 
1>JpegReadWrite.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol jpeg_CreateDecompress referenced in function main 
1>JpegReadWrite.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol jpeg_destroy_decompress referenced in function main 
1>JpegReadWrite.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol jpeg_mem_src referenced in function main 
1>JpegReadWrite.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol jpeg_read_header referenced in function main 
1>JpegReadWrite.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol jpeg_start_decompress referenced in function main 
1>JpegReadWrite.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol jpeg_read_scanlines referenced in function main 
1>JpegReadWrite.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol jpeg_finish_decompress referenced in function main         

1>D:\tonbo_stuti\libjpeg\jpeg-build\lib\libjpeg.a : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'          

1>C:\Users\tonbo\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\serverAppl\x64\Debug\JpegReadWrite.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals 1>Done building project "JpegReadWrite.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

I am thoroughly confused on how to make libJPEG work and don't understand what's going on as I am new to the Visual Studio environment. I checked that these symbols actually are defined in "jpeglib.h" and I have included that. I thought I can do the same steps for a .a file as for a .lib file, but something is going wrong.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: 1>D:\tonbo_stuti\libjpeg\jpeg-build\lib\libjpeg.a : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64' <--- You are building for different platforms, i.e. libjpeg was built with x86, but you try to link it in x64 context. Recompile libjpeg with x64 and try again.

Comment: The relevant part seems to be "LNK4272: library machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'". Maybe the library is built for a 32 bit machine.

Comment: Thank you. @MABVT could you advise me how to recompile libjpeg with x64? This was what I followed last time in the Mingw installation instructions: 
cd /d/tmp/jpeg-9b
./configure --prefix=/d/tmp/jpeg-build
make
make install
I think by default it took x86, how do I change that?

Comment: @StutiRastogi See answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Converting to answer:

You need to use the same target, i.e. libjpeg x64.

If you want to use MingW, I recommend doing as below:

### Installing MSys2 64-bit

1. Go to http://www.msys2.org/ and click on “msys2_x86_64-.exe” on the top-middle of the page.
2. Follow the installation instructions on the Web-Page but **DO NOT
   CHANGE the installation path**. This will take a while!

### Installing additional software

1. If no MSys-Shell instance is open, otherwise step 4

   - Open the Explorer and navigate the the msys2 installation directory (usually *C:\msys64*).
   - Double-Click on *msys2_shell.cmd*
2. Enter the command ***pacman -Su***  for each of the below listed names (case-sensitive)! If asked for confirmation (Y/n),
   enter Y and hit the Enter-key. E.g. **pacman -Su automake**

   - m4
   - autoconf
   - automake
   - pkg-config
   - make
   - libtool

### Installing the x86 and x86_64 toolchains

The base installation of MSys2-x64 comes without any build-toolchain. In order to compile for x86 and x86_64, we need to install the toolchains for i686 and x86_64 manually.

Therefore, perform the subsequent steps in the MSys-Shell instance:

1. If no MSys-Shell instance is open:
   a.  Open the Explorer and navigate the the msys2 installation directory (usually C:\msys64).
   b.  Double-Click on *msys2_shell.cmd*
2. Enter **pacman -Su mingw-w64-i686-toolchain**, hit enter and confirm with “Y”
3. Wait a while
4. Enter **pacman -Su mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain**, hit enter and confirm with “Y”
5. Wait a while

### Going for libjpeg

1. Download source and store in  (wherever you want)
2. Launch a mingw32 shell (Goto the MSys installation directory and click on "**mingw32.exe**"
3. In the shell, enter "*cd* " to go to your source!
4. Enter "*touch generate_x86_install.sh*"
5. Open the file in your favorite editor (I use notepad++)
6. Copy the below contents into it
7. Run the shell script from mingw32-shell by entering "*./generate_x86_install.sh*"

```html
#! /bin/bash

if [ "${MSYSTEM}" != "MINGW32" ]; then
 echo "You must run this script from a MingW32 shell!"
 exit;
fi

PWD="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
TGT=${PWD}/deploy/Win32


mkdir -p ${TGT}/include
mkdir -p ${TGT}/lib
mkdir -p ${TGT}/bin 
mkdir -p ${TGT}/man/man1

./configure static --prefix=${TGT} --exec-prefix=${TGT} --
includedir=${TGT}/include --libdir=${TGT}/lib

echo "----------- CLEAN           -----------"
make clean
echo "----------- MAKE            -----------"
make
echo "----------- INSTALL         -----------"
make install
echo "----------- INSTALL-LIB     -----------"
make install-lib
echo "----------- INSTALL-HEADERS -----------"
make install-headers
echo "----------- CHECKING OUTPUT -----------"
objdump -f  ${TGT}/lib/libjpeg.a | grep "file format"
```

### Finally

Do the same thing with "**mingw64.exe**", BUT:

1. Copy the generate_x86_install.sh and rename it to generate_x64_install.sh
2. Replace all occurrences of "**32**" with "**64**"

### Conclusion

Cross-Compiling with MSys2 and the MingW toolchains is awesome and you should have both: x86 and x86_64 libjpegs.

The objdump in the end should display the proper architectures.
E.g.:

```html
// x86 output
jcapimin.o:     file format pe-i386
jcapistd.o:     file format pe-i386
jctrans.o:     file format pe-i386
jcparam.o:     file format pe-i386
jdatadst.o:     file format pe-i386
// ...

// x64 output
jcapimin.o:     file format pe-x86-64
jcapistd.o:     file format pe-x86-64
jctrans.o:     file format pe-x86-64
jcparam.o:     file format pe-x86-64
jdatadst.o:     file format pe-x86-64
// ...
```

You finally just have to link against the respective lib in deploy/Win32/lib or deploy/Win64/lib.

I tested it on my own machine having two wonderfully built libjpeg.a :D

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, but the shell script gave me errors for both Win32 and Win64.
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: loading site script /mingw32/etc/config.site
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `static': machine `static' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/sh ./config.sub static failed
_(Continued in next comment)_

Comment: ./generate_x86_install.sh: line 18: --libdir=/d/tonbo_stuti/jpegsr9b/jpeg-9b/deploy/Win32/lib: No such file or directory
------- CLEAN           -------
make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop.
------- MAKE            --------
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
-------- INSTALL         --------
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
----------- INSTALL-LIB     -----------
make: *** No rule to make target 'install-lib'.  Stop.
------- INSTALL-HEADERS -------
make: *** No rule to make target 'install-headers'.  Stop.
_(continued)_

Comment: ----------- CHECKING OUTPUT -----------
C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\objdump.exe: 'D:/tonbo_stuti/jpegsr9b/jpeg-9b/deploy/Win32/lib/libjpeg.a': No such file

Comment: So I thought static was giving the issue, and I used the configure command without static. I got the .a files, and when linking the x64 one I got 2 new unresolved errors:
`1>libjpeg.a(jerror.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___iob_func referenced in function output_message
1>libjpeg.a(jmemmgr.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sscanf referenced in function jinit_memory_mgr`
Any idea how to get rid of these? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: No the problem is the file system structure. Static was fine. It can't find the lib-dir. It is not created :/ How do your shell scripts look like?

Comment: But they were created. All the mkdir operations were successful, and I checked if the folders were present which they were. I did get ----------- INSTALL-LIB     -----------
make: *** No rule to make target 'install-lib'.  Stop.
----------- INSTALL-HEADERS -----------
make: *** No rule to make target 'install-headers'.  Stop.
when I tried without static. I don't know why the script couldn't find the directories :(

Comment: which libjpeg version do you use?

Comment: Was able to fix the two unresolved symbol errors:

- Added FILE _iob[] = { *stdin, *stdout, *stderr };
extern "C" FILE * __cdecl __iob_func(void) { return _iob; }
to stdafx.h
- Added legacy_stdio_definitions.lib; to the linker input.

My program still has issues, but at least it ran! So thanks for all the input :)

Comment: Ah ok... So what you could try also is to install the "gcc" package in MSys2 using pacman -Su gcc, maybe this provides you with what you need... I missed this one above possibly.

Comment: Yes, thanks! Got it working finally with all the different tricks. :)