# Compile libjpeg using Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022, libjpeg

Was anybody able to install [libjpeg](https://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/) using Visual Studio 2022? I've tried to run `nmake /f makefile.vc setup-v17` from the "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022". While [this should be the correct approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63913230), I'm receiving the error message `fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'setup-v17'`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sorry to ask some basic checks but sometimes, it can unlock some problems...

First of all, can you ensure you’ve checked the item "Desktop development with C++" in the Workloads tab of Visual Studio Installer ([ref.](https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/ijg/blob/main/install.txt))?

Can you check that you execute command in the same directory where you have drop & extract the makefile.vc file ?

Like preconized [Vinz in an answer of your shared post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50571327/5449595), have you try to iterate on version to be sure like setup-v10, setup-v11, ... until setup-v17 to be sure that is the correct version ?

Can you test instead of *nmake /f makefile.vs setup-v17* command this :

```
nmake /f makefile.vs setupcopy-v17
```

I hope it can help you, GLHF !